# Release apk com.facebook.react.common.javascriptexception:null is not an object (evaluating t(r(d[1])).default.direction react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Description
when i publish the app in play store . it is showing the error. but it is working perfectly in emulator.

React Native version: 0.59.8

NodeJS version: v14.3.0

React Native Environment Info:

System:

OS: Windows 10

CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz

Memory: 4.16 GB / 7.91 GB

Binaries:
npm: 6.14.5 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please fill React Native version and add NodeJS version

Comment: react native 0.59.8, node-v14.3.0

Comment: Did you find a solution for this??